# Cómo obtener contenido via selector de un HTML

Tags: html, html-select, selectores, selectores-css

tengo el sitio: [elpopular.pe](https://www.elpopular.pe/actualidad-y-policiales/229670-fiscalia-libero-madre-castigaba-hijas-encerrandolas-tanques-agua) que tiene sus noticias relacionado en medio de un contenido de html

y lo quiero es extraer el enlace de la etiqueta **LEE ESTO** y **MIRA TAMBIÉN**, ambos son noticias relacionados, normalmente con selectores una etiqueta debe tener una CLASE(.) o ID(#), pero justo el texto **LEE MÁS y MIRA TAMBIÉN**  se encuentran en una etiqueta **strong** que no tiene clase ni id. para capturar datos via **XPATH** y **SELECTOR** utilizo una extension de chrome que se llama : [scrapemate beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrapemate-beta/daiomapeacamgnofkkmiaollhidcndld)

intenté crear mi selector así: `.glr-node-content a`, pero me selecciona todo el contenido del sitio; solo quiero obtener las noticias relacionados, ósea la linea que dice ** LEE ESTO** su enlace, cómo seria mi selector por el texto(LEE ESTO y MIRA TAMBIÉN) en específico ?, gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:
**explicacion**

1. seleccionamos el elemento `.glr-node-content`
2. seleccionamos los hijos `div`
3. seleccionamos el elemento `5` con `nth-child()`
4. seleccionamos el elemnto `a`
5. luego de ello solo seria extraer su `href`

   document.querySelector(".glr-node-content div:nth-child(5) a");
   document.querySelector(".glr-node-content div:nth-child(22) a");

> lo mas cercano que pude llegar a seleccionar los elementos con css

**ahora intentando con xpath**

seleccionamos el class `glr-node-content` luego su `div`
luego su `strong` que empieze con el texto `LEE`
seleccionamos el elemento siguiente `a` y obtenemos su `href`

```
//*[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," glr-node-content ")]/div/strong[starts-with(text(),'MIRA')]/following-sibling::*[1]/self::a/@href <br>

//*[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," ")," glr-node-content ")]/div/strong[starts-with(text(),'LEE')]/following-sibling::*[1]/self::a/@href
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero document.querySelectorAll creo que seria ejecutar con Javascipt, quiero solo el selector

Comment: el selector es el que te acabo de dar en la explicacion :v el codigo js es para que veas los resultados :v es el indice  1 :v

Comment: por ejemplo mi selector seria: div > strong + a 
pero me trae todos las Urls de todos los strong, yo solo quiero del strong contenga el texto : LEE ESTO y MIRA TAMBIÉN

Answer (score 0):

No puedes seleccionar un tag por su contenido con un selector CSS. Creo recordar que antes habia un selector de contenido, pero fue depreciado y ya no te puedes fiar de que funcione.
Si no puedes/quieres usar un id o clase especificos, tendras que encontrar un selector unico que solo identifique a ese elemento.

Si en el enlace hay una cadena de texto unica, podrias hacer algo como

```
a[href*="elpopular"]
```

que seleccionaria los  que tengan esa cadena de texto en el enlace.

Amplio con una solucion en javascript:

```
element = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (item of element) {
  if (item.previousSibling.innerHTML=="MIRA TAMBIÉN:"){
    //aqui haces lo que quieras con el enlace
    console.log("este lo tiene"+item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Montaycabe, en mi caso primero tendría que buscar el texto del Strong por ejemplo: MIRA TAMBIÉN:, y capturar el primer href, la verdad se me hace complicado armar el selector, como seria en este caso?, gracias.
`<p><strong class="">MIRA TAMBIÉN:&nbsp;</strong><a href="https://www.elpopular.pe/series/salud/227300-salud-cuidado-infecciones-vaginales-verano" target="_blank" class="">Salud: cuidado con las infecciones vaginales en verano</a></p>`

Comment: El otro seria: `<p><strong class="">LEE MÁS:&nbsp;</strong><a href="https://www.elpopular.pe/series/salud/227358-salud-6-enfermedades-comunes-verano-prevenirlas" target="_blank" class="">Salud: Las 6 enfermedades más comunes en verano y cómo prevenirlas</a></p>` , el post se encuentra en: https://www.elpopular.pe/series/salud/227693-salud-aire-acondicionado-perjudicar-salud

Comment: Te he ampliado la respuesta con una rutina en javascript que chequea si los enlaces estan precedidos por un elemento con "MIRA TAMBIÉN:" (y mejor quita el `&nbsp;` , no s una buena practica para espaciar)

Comment: Montaycabe, crees que seria posible solo con selectores?, no sé si habra un especie de buscador por ejemplo: MIRA TAMBIÉN:

Comment: No, como te cuento, solo por css no es posible a no ser que le pongas un id, una clase, un atributo, o tenga una cadena de texto identificable en el href o algo similar.
No hay ningun selector CSS por contenido.